# C++ calculate socket transfer speed

Tags: android, c++, multithreading, sockets

Greetigs,

I want to measure the transfer speeds between an application running on my PC and the phone which are connected through a wireless network. My phone is running Android and is acting as an echo server. Everything it receives through a socket it echoes back.

On the PC side I wrote a small application which has two threads. One generates packets (128K, but I can control it) and sends them to the phone (the WriteThread). The packets have a timestamp value at the beginning showing the time that the packet was sent. After an entire packet is sent my write thread waits for an event to be signaled. The event is signaled by the read thread when the entire packet has been received. The read thread extracts the timestamp from the packet and calculates the roundtrip lag - the time it took for the packet to go to the phone and return.

**My sockets on both sides ( phone and PC ) are non-blocking.**

My program is written in C++:

```
// WriteThread
int totalBytesWritten = 0;
int bytesWritten = 0;
const int packetSize = 128 * 1024;
char pBuffer[packetSize];
int packetCount = 1000;
int iterations = packetCount;

while ( iterations > 0 )
{
   if ( totalBytesWritten < bytesWritten )
   {
     if ( generatePacketEvent.isSignaled() )
     {
        GenerateBuffer( pBuffer, packetSize );
        generatePacketEvent.Reset();
        totalBytesWritten = 0;
        iterations --;
     }

     int bytesWritten = CSocketUtils::Write( m_socket, pBuffer + totalBytesWritten, packetSize - totalBytesWritten );
     if ( bytesWritten > 0 ) totalBytesWritten += bytesWritten;
   }
}

// Read thread
int totalBytesRead = 0;
int bytesRead = 0;
int expectedPackets = 100;
int packetsReceived = 0;
const int packetSize = 128 * 1024;
char pBuffer[packetSize];

while ( packetsReceived < packetsExpected )
{
   if ( totalBytesReceived < packetSize )
   {
      bytesRead = CSocketUtils::Read( m_socket, pBuffer + totalBytesRead, packetSize - totalBytesRead );
      if ( bytesRead > 0 )
      {
        totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
      }
   }
   else
   {
      totalBytesRead = 0;
      packetReceivedEvent.Signal();

      uint32_t timestamp = 0;
      memcpy( &timestamp, pBuffer, sizeof( uint32_t ) );
      uint32_t roundtrip = CurrentTimeMilliseconds() - timestamp;
   }
}

// Generate Buffer data
void GenerateBuffer( char* pBuffer, int size )
{
    uint32_t timestamp = CurrentTimeMilliseconds();
    memcpy( pBuffer, &timestamp, sizeof( uint32_t ) );
    for (int i = sizeof( uint32_t ); i < size; i ++ )
    {
      pBuffer[i] = rand() % 255;
    }
}
```

**How would I measure the speed at which my application is sending / receiving data to / from my phone?**

**I cannot change the Echo application of the phone to modify the packets that it is receiving! So there is no way to add a timestamp on the phone side.**

At first I was accumulating the bytes returned by the CSocketUtils::Write ( which calls send() ) and having a timer measure one second. When the timer expired I would take the accumulated bytes as the write speed. But that produced 12MB/s and it took me 30sto send 12mb of data, so there is no way that is accurate. Then I started measuring time it took to send the whole packet, but that again did not help, because that way I am measuring how fast the OS is filling the socket buffer :(

Comment: Do you need to measure lag or throughput?  Are you only interested in round trip time, or are you interested in one way times?

Comment: I am interested in both roundtrip lag as well as throughput. So both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a timestamp as you send the packet, when the phone recives the packet then generate a timestamp also. Then subtract the time from the phone timestamp by the PC timestamp to give you a time difference. Then bytes sent divided by the time-gap will give you your bytes-per-time interval speed.

e.g.

`recive time - sent time = time gap" // lets say 2ms
// When you sent the packet, you sent 8 bytes, so:
8 / 2 = 4bytes/s //(bytes / timegap = speed)`

Comment: Which will work as long as your computer and phone times are synchronized to within milliseconds, which may or may not be realistic.

Comment: I cannot chanage the data on the Android device. That is the requirment. I can only echo back the data.

Comment: I don't think you saw my comment. I have a restriction that I cannot change the phone application, so I cannot make it send the timestamp the packet was received.